# Circle to Circle Collision of moving Sprites

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

i needed help attaching circle1 Sprite to circle2 Sprite on collision onto the same point where they are getting collided, and both circles are moving with Action.
Like this,

[image: image|502x485]

Attaching means, when circle1 and circle2 sprites get collided, i am removing circle1 Sprite from scene and creating new sprite at that same position of circle1.

I have implemented following code for collision
....
float dx = circle1.x - circle2.x;
float dy = circle1.y - circle2.y;
float distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

if (distance < circle1.radius + circle2.radius) {
    // collision detected
   // removing older sprite
   // creating of new sprite
}

Its working perfectly when one circle sprite in motion and another is static.

But when both are in motion, at some points ( collision point like bottom-left/ up-right of circle2 ) its get attached little over circle2 sprite and it happens at random times so i couldn't able to detect the error.

I want to attach new Sprite at exact point where collision occurred like this,
[image: 2]

Anybody have done it before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is common during collision resolution in physics systems.

You'll need to do some [collision penetration resolution](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Collisions/Collision-resolution) before you start removing/creating sprites.

This usually means finding how much the two objects overlap:
`penetration = (player.position - enemy.position).length() + abs(player.radius - enemy.radius)`
Then move them away from each other:
`player.position += (player.position - enemy.position).unit() * penetration * 0.5
enemy.position -= (player.position - enemy.position).unit() * penetration * 0.5`

I assume that player and enemy's position is a Vector3 with length and [unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) functions. You may have to adjust who is += and -=. Also, you have an [abs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) function somewhere.

The 0.5 will move both objects away 50% of the distance, this is usually adjusted to reflect the relative weight of each object (eg. `player.weight / (player.weight + enemy.weight`).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but the game i developing do not allows me to move second sprite( enemy circle ), somehow i have to adjust player shooting sprite only.
In game , enemy sprites are moving randomly and player sprite circle is shooting from left to right on same y-axis.
I can calculate collapsed area in respect of x-axis position, but when sprites

Comment: i wanted to calculate collapsed area according to y-axis also .. to place/attach shooter sprite at collision point